# Do some flowers excrete urea or uric acid?

Tags: biochemistry, botany

Sometimes when I sniff a flower up close, I can't but help smelling a faint urine like odor. From my layperson's understanding, uric acid and urea both are responsible for giving urine its characteristic smell. Do flowers excrete either of these chemicals?

Comment: are you just smelling ammonia?

Comment: It's very faint. It's the same smell you get in some cigars too, except they call it floral.

Comment: May I know, is it for all flowers or only a few? Can you identify those flowers ?

Comment: The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure.

Comment: For example, did you try searching for "flower smell urine"? This gives multiple results including an article in [Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/you-smell-flowers-i-smell/).